# Makefile function defintion arguments

Tags: makefile, automation

I have a Makefile that looks like this:

```
define cap
  @echo $1
endef

f:
    $(foreach x,$(shell command),$(call cap,$x))
```

command outputs

```
x1
x2
x3
x4
x5
```

make f gives me

```
x1 @echo x2 @echo x3 @echo x4 @echo x5
```

My desired output is

```
x1
x2
x3
x4
x5
```

I am not sure why cap prints echo like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple: each iteration of the `foreach` generates the string `@echo ..` which are all then appended together and sent to the shell.  So after the foreach loop has finished expanding, your recipe looks like this:

```
@echo x1 @echo x2 @echo x3 @echo x4 @echo x5
```

If you run that in the shell, it will give the output you see.

If you want to run these as separate shell commands you can use `;` to separate them, but you have to remove the `@` because that is not a valid shell operator:

```
define cap
   echo $1
endef

f:
         @$(foreach x,$(shell command),$(call cap,$x);)
```

Comment: Thats what I was looking for